# Comparing 2 objects using JUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have a service which I want to test:

```
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;
    //... other functions 

    @Override
    public Department getDepartment(int depid) {
        return departmentDao.getDepartment(depid);
    }
}
```

and here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:sdnext-servlet.xml")
public class TestDepartmentDetails {

    Department department  = new Department();
    DepartmentServiceImpl service = new DepartmentServiceImpl();

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao myDao;


    @Test
    public void testGetDepartment(){
        assertEquals("lalalalalalala", service.getDepartment(98).getDepName());
    }
```

Why it gives me a failure and throws a `NullPointerException`? Is there any other solution?

Note: This is an application which uses Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: Because you create the service with new and not autowire it

Comment: why not importing it ?? ..  as far as i know i have to import the class i want to test ?? is that right ??

Comment: You shoul autowire it, because it is a spring bean.

Comment: You don´t have a problem comparing two objects using JUnit. You misused the workflow of **Dependency Injection**, because of that you got a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are creating instances manually which is not the right way while using Spring.

Please refer to the Spring docs below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

You have to autowire **DepartmentServiceImpl** service instead of **DepartmentDao** in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:sdnext-servlet.xml")
    public class TestDepartmentDetails {
        @Autowired
        DepartmentService   service;
        @Test
        public void testGetDepartment(){
            assertEquals("lalalalalalala", service.getDepartment(98).getDepName());
        }
```